# Is there a straightforward way to stop a service in response to a user clicking a notification?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'd like the following behavior:
The user clicks a notification and Android stops my Service.

The problem is that stopping a Service requires a call to stopService and I cannot easily create a PendingIntent that does that.

So the only way I found to do this is to have my Service receive a special Intent extra that causes the Service to call stopSelf and stop.

Is there a simpler way to directly cancel a Service from a notification click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a simple `BroadcastReceiver` that does the `stopService()` call, and use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent` to trigger it. That `BroadcastReceiver` could be registered in the manifest or via `registerReceiver()` by the `Service` itself (in the latter case, it would do `stopSelf()` rather than `stopService()`).

That's probably not any simpler than what you have, though, and there is no way to directly trigger a `stopService()` call from a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: I've used this for a long time but this doesn't work anymore. Starting with Android L (5.0), you will get a DeadObjectException if the user swiped your app our of the recents list and caused Android to kill the main task and restart the service (happens if you have a local service with some UI that can be swiped out)

Comment: @gnobal: `DeadObjectException` only occurs through binding AFAIK. This solution does not involve binding.

Comment: neither does mine. I do use startService, though. But since I'm too lazy to provide a small example to show this, I'll trust that it's just my app that's not working well. In any case, I switched to a different solution you offered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11145822/7748 :)

Answer (score 13):

Thanks CommonsWare.

Here is a quick illustration of your solution for those who are interested.

Code is in the service class.

> ```
> // Create Notification 
> private void initNotification() {     
>   //Register a receiver to stop Service   
>   registerReceiver(stopServiceReceiver, new IntentFilter("myFilter"));
>   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("myFilter"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>   notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,contentIntent);  
>   mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);  
> ...
> }
>
>
>
> //We need to declare the receiver with onReceive function as below
> protected BroadcastReceiver stopServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {   
>   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>   stopSelf();
>   }
> };
> ```

Comment: does the receiver need to be "unregistered" ever?

Comment: @MobileMon, yes, it should, before 'stopSelf()'

Comment: I based roughly on your code ... but it is not working, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956088/not-receiving-notification-click-in-service