# Make an intent kill a service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm trying to make a foreground notification for a service that has a button that when presses, will end the service. I have created the button but I have no idea what to make my intent to end the service.

```
public Notification getNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(serviceContext, NotificationGenerator.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(serviceContext, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(serviceContext)
            .setContentTitle(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .addAction(R.drawable.remove_button,"End Service", endService);
    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    return n;
}
```

Intent endService = new Intent();
What should I set endService to to do so?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is to send a Broadcast to the Service.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145679/stopping-a-background-service-from-notification