# Not receiving notification click in service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I try to run a background service and display a persistent notification. When the notification is clicked, the service (providing NanoHTTPD webserver) should be stopped.

The `onReceive` never seems to be called when tapping the notification. "Stop" is not logged. (while "Start" is.

My code below is roughly based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476094/288568.

```
public class Webserver extends IntentService {

private final String TAG = "MyAMWebserver";

public static final int PORT = 1234;

public static Boolean isRunning = false;

private MyWebserver server;
private ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager(this);

private NotificationManager notificationManger;


public Webserver() {
    super("webserver-service");
}

//We need to declare the receiver with onReceive function as below
protected BroadcastReceiver stopServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stop");
        unregisterReceiver(stopServiceReceiver);
        stopSelf();
        isRunning = false;
        notificationManger.cancel(01);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
    // If a Context object is needed, call getApplicationContext() here.

    try {
        server = new MyWebserver();
        isRunning = true;

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("myMapWebserver");
        Intent intent = new Intent("myMapWebserver");
        registerReceiver(stopServiceReceiver, intentFilter);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent
```

= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

```
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Webserver Running").setContentText("Click here to Stop Webserver").setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .getNotification();

        notificationManger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManger.notify(01, notification);

        Log.d(TAG, "Started");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // This describes what will happen when service is triggered
}

public class MyWebserver extends NanoHTTPD {

....
```

Comment: obviously because `IntentService` "lives only" until `onHandleIntent` is finished ...

Comment: How can I make it live longer? Do I need some loop for running the webserver?

Comment: use normal `Service` not `IntentService` ... IntenService is(in short): do the job(onHandleIntent) on different thread and shutdown ... also you didn't shutdown the nano server itself nowhere

Comment: Got it - works - awesome ... if you want post an answer