# I want to close my application when the user touch the notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to close my application when the user touch the notification, this is my code for notification code in main activity

[image: Screenshot]

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new           NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.earth);
    builder.setContentTitle("RadioPlanet");
    builder.setContentText("Touch here to stop");
    int mll=001;
    NotificationManager mNotification=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotification.notify(mll,builder.build());
```

Comment: What do you mean by close `Service` or ?

Comment: System.exit(0);

Comment: When user minimize the program , it will play some music, so when user press the notification it vl stop if i usr System.exit(0)

Comment: That means you are using service to play music on background ?

Comment: Yes dude  @W4R10CK

Comment: Follow this  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241682/is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-stop-a-service-in-response-to-a-user-clicking

Comment: its not i need...